# Spark Cassandra Connector timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

```
val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis - (2629746 * 1000)
sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "users").select("id").where("timestamp > ?", timestamp).cassandraCount()
```

"timestamp" here is a standard cassandra type timestamp and formatted as such.

I want to convert my timestamp to the correct format so i can find any users record that has a timestamp that was updated in the last 30 days but I am not sure how to format it correctly in scala. I see there is a TimestampFormatter class in the datastax cassandra connector but I can't make it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would not really use that approach there, you would instead assign a `timeuuid` to individual updates. So an update would have the clustering key as `timestamp timeuuid` with `CLUSTERING ORDER BY(timestamp descending)`.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs

sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "users")
  .select("id")
  .where("timestamp > ?", UUIDs.startOf(timeuuid))
  .cassandraCount()
```

Or you could just use `minTimeUUID` and `maxTimeUUID`.

```
val now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)
val start = now.plusDays(-30)


sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "users")
  .select("id")
  .where("timestamp >= minTimeUUID(start.toISOString))
  .and(("timestamp <= maxTimeUUID(now.toISOString)))
  .cassandraCount()
```

Comment: How do this help me get all records in the last 30 days? I also have my timestamp column as type timestamp now so I need to be able to use what I already have. edit: I guess you meant UUIDs.startOf(unixTimestamp).

Comment: @user3345171 What you have is bad because it's not inherently unique, you never use a raw timstamp as part of a primary, that's fairly textbook. I've expanded the `minTimeUUID` and `maxTimeUUID` suggestion, that's the standard way of doing range queries in Cassandra, not using raw dates.